# Is there any way to upload an image file in the body of a HTTP POST request in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have an API which requires an image along with few other parameters in its request body. In postman, the request parameters can be added in **form-data** (as shown in the attached image).

How can I implement it in Jmeter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

other parameters: `userDataJson`, `requestReferenceId`, etc. should go to "Parameters" tab.

Also be aware that given you can execute your request successfully in Postman you should be able to record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html).

1. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008893713-How-do-I-configure-Postman-to-work-through-a-proxy-)

   [image]
2. [Copy the file(s) you will be uploading to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter/)
3. Execute request in Postman
4. That's it, JMeter will capture the request and store the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

Comment: The first solution does not work due to the config of API. The proxy solution worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [Use multipart/form-data](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request), add file in Files Upload tab and parameters in Parameters tab

> if you are sending a file using a multipart form, the query string will be created using the multipart form specifications.

If it doesn't work you can use [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)  while sending postman request

> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder allows JMeter to intercept and record your actions while you browse your web application with your normal browser. JMeter will create test sample objects and store them directly into your test plan as you go (so you can view samples interactively while you make them).
>   Ensure you read this wiki page to setup correctly JMeter.
>
> To use the recorder, add the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder element. Right-click on the Test Plan element to get the Add menu: (Add → Non-Test Elements → HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder ).